# To Search Universal Tweets Via Twitter API v1.1

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, twitter

Hi this might eventually turn out to be a stupid question but i'd rather ask!! Its regarding GET search/tweets Twitter API v1.1. As documented by Twitter this particular API is designed to accept numerous parameter against which a search is performed and tweets are returned. One of these parameters is "geocode" which accepts `value is specified by "latitude,longitude,radius", where radius units must be specified as either "mi" (miles) or "km" (kilometers)` https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets.

Its quite alright if is set those parameter values.

My question is since it is "geocode" optional will not setting them return me universal tweets? or is there any other way I could find universal tweets using `GET search/tweets Twitter API v1.1`.

Also, Ive tried Streaming API `POST statuses/filter` with very indifferent/unsatisfactory results

P.S As per requirement of my app I need to search apps both universally and locally, as per users choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems if you skip the "geocode" parameter, Universal Tweets are returned!!